# Appium with Protractor: Working with AngularJS Asynchronous Calls

Tags: angularjs, protractor, appium

My Hybrid android app is built with `angularjs` library with lots of `Asynchronous` calls all over. How can I integrate `Appium with Protractor`, so that I can check for complete page loadings including asynchronous calls and other data bindings. My app is developed and ported as `APK` and not browsed in a browser. Am able to execute my selenium scripts but asynchronous calls is the place where I have stuck.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As of now Protractor doesn't officially support appium configurations. However there is a help file that is available in Protractor docs. All you need to do is update your conf.js file to include the appium configurations and remember to start your appium server before you run the test script. 
To your question, you need to have below points ready -

1. Start your avd
2. Install the .apk file in your avd that you will be invoking through appium
3. Start the appium server using command - **appium &**
4. Update your protractor conf.js file to include appium android/chrome configurations. More details about configurations can be found in the below link.

Here's the link to it - [Protractor-Appium Setup](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/mobile-setup.md)

Comment: Hybrid application can be automated through protractor? or you are telling how to configure protractor for automating web application in Mobile browser. If the former is true, please tell me how to automate an Hybrid app in Protractor, as of now we are unsuccessful in that.

Comment: No, you cannot automate hybrid apps with protractor alone. However you can use appium to automate it. So i have given a link which integrates protractor and appium. Using appium you can automate hybrid apps and using protractor you can handle angular calls. As both appium and protractor work on the same selenium webdriver concept, you can write javascript code to automate your app

Comment: Girish Sortur: As per the Github issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1798, it is still not implemented, they have todo team for this and they are saying ETA!

Comment: Right harsha.cs. I dint say its officially supported yet. Please see my post above. You can still use it unofficially.